# Price is not correct when edit order in back end magento

Tags: php, magento, edit, backend

I have a problem when editing an order in the back-end of Magento. In the front end,  I have custom price when add Product to cart. Price is good in back end ( show and correct in order) but when I click edit order, the price is not correct in `Item` order. I have seen it get the default price of product. I try to catch event sales_quote_save_before and try code

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote(); 
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
{
 $item->setCustomPrice($price);
 $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
}
```

but I only set custom price for each item in order, I can not set Subtotal and row Subtotal for order. could you tell me how to do that? Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set subtotals and other related attributes as following:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)->setStoreId($storeId); // if saving new one

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10012345');    //if loading product
$order->setSubtotal($sub_total)
$order->setBaseSubtotal($base_sub_total)
$order->setTaxAmount($some_tax_price)
$order->setGrandTotal($grand_total)
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total);
```

Do note that if you make changes in this manner then some reports might not calculate the order(s) correctly (such as dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Can try following solution -

Can create solution via Magento module

1) 
config.xml, need add block with event **sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item** - like

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
            <observers>
                <orderpricesfromoldorder_old_prices>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Magefast_OrderPricesFromOldOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesEventOrderItemToQuoteItemPrices</method>
                </orderpricesfromoldorder_old_prices>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

2) Observer file with function/method - like

```
public function salesEventOrderItemToQuoteItemPrices($observer)
{

    /** @var $orderItem Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
    $orderItem = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderItem();
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    // Do not import giftmessage data if order is reordered
    $order = $orderItem->getOrder();
    if ($order && $order->getReordered()) {
        return $this;
    }

    // mage::log($orderItem->getData('price'));
    // mage::log($quoteItem->getProduct()->getData('price'));

    if ($orderItem->getData('price') && $orderItem->getData('price') != '') {

        $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getData('price'));
        $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getData('price'));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You can check Magento Core module - Mage_GiftMessage

So, when will edit Order via Adminpanel - prices will same.
but be carefull with low prices :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Magefast's solution, I've found that you also need to `setCustomPrice()` on the parent item when working with Configurable products. The quote will contain both the simple + configurable product, you want to make sure both rows get updated with the custom price.

Observer Method:

```
public function setCustomPriceForItem($observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if ($session != null && !$session->getReordered() && $orderItem->getOriginalPrice() != $orderItem->getPrice()) {            
        $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());

        //also update the price on the parent item
        if ($parentQuoteItem = $quoteItem->getParentItem()) {                  
            $parentQuoteItem->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
            $parentQuoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Also see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62422/getting-quote-cart-items-programatically-shows-duplicate-skus-for-both-the-con